# CSS create two lines of texts and align both to an iframe bottom

Tags: html, css, iframe

this is my HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<iframe src="http://server.com" width="30" height="30" seamless="seamless" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" class="ifcheckif"></iframe>
<div class="texts"> 
first line of text, smaller <span>second line,aligned to the iframe bottom, bigger and bold.</span> 
</div>
</div>
```

what I'd like to obtain, is the iframe aligned to the bottom of the two lines.

I cannot modify the HTML, but I can insert any CSS, actually everything is managed in this way:

```
.container{
    text-align: center;
}

.ifcheckif {
    display: inline;
}

.texts {
    font-size: 0.688rem!important;
}

.texts span {
    display: block !important;
    font-size: 1.000rem !important;
    font-weight: 700 !important;
    padding-left: 30px;
}
```

but the result isn't what I want, actually the iframe is aligned to the top of the first line, while I would like it aligned at the bottom of the second line, or more more more better, in the "middle" of both.
May I achieve this with solely CSS? may I ask your help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [`display` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) to be `inline-block` rather than `inline` and do the same with the `.texts` `div`, like so:

```css
.container{
  text-align:center;
}
iframe{
  background:#000;
  border:0;
  display:inline-block;
  height:60px;
  width:60px;
}
.text{
  display:inline-block;
}
.text span {
    display:block;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-left:30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <iframe src="#"></iframe>
  <div class="text">first line of text, smaller <span>second line,aligned to the iframe bottom, bigger and bold.</span></div>
</div>
```

If that doesn't give you the exact positioning you want, you can use the [`vertical-align` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) to adjust it.

Comment: this works perfectly, really don't know why I din't think about it from the beginning, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that using `position:absolute` on your text and iframe.

```css
.container{
    text-align: center;
}

.ifcheckif {
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    top:2.2em;
}

.texts {
    top:0;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 0.688rem!important;
}

.texts span {
    display: block !important;
    font-size: 1.000rem !important;
    font-weight: 700 !important;
    padding-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<iframe src="www.xyz.com" width="200" height="200" seamless="seamless" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" class="ifcheckif"></iframe>
<div class="texts"> 
first line of text, smaller <span>second line,aligned to the iframe bottom, bigger and bold.</span> 
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but the absolute positioning results in some problems, as the entire line become left aligned. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by giving the outer div a relative position and the text div absolute. Then you can give paddings and margins accordingly, e.g. try this css:

```
.container{
    text-align: center;
    position:relative;
}

.ifcheckif {
    display: inline;
    margin-top:20px;

}

.texts {
    font-size: 0.688rem!important;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
}

.texts span {
    display: block !important;
    font-size: 1.000rem !important;
    font-weight: 700 !important;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-top:40px
}
```